# JSON undefined when Site added to Local Intranet

Tags: json, internet-explorer, security-zone

So we have a website that makes use of the JSON object as shown here.

```
    $.each(JSON.parse($hdnSearchCriteria.val()), function (k, v) {
        parseCriteria();
    });
```

Our network guys here added our domain to our Local Intranet, and since then, anyone accessing the site from inside of our network gets a 'JSON undefined' error when the code above is hit.

However, this only occurs when running IE and FireFox.  It works find in Google Chrome.

We are using IE 9, 10 and 11. We do not have any versions older than 9.
Firefox is version 26.0

I would appreciate anyone being able to shed light on this one.

**UPDATE:**  I updated FireFox to 27.0.1 and this is no longer an issue in Firefox, no only in IE.

**UPDATE 2 and Solution**

The problem was Compatibility Mode.  Unfortunately, since Microsoft removed the Compatibility button from recent releases of IE, there isn't a clear indication of when a site is running in compatibility mode.  In my case it was, but since I did not see the 'broken page' icon anywhere, I assumed that it was not.

It turns out that when the Group Policy that moved the site into the Local Intranet Zone, the "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View" setting's default value of True went into effect.

Answer (score 0):

IE 7 or below doesn't support JSON natively. You will need to use a library likey [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to polyfill the functionality.

http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: We do not have any machines running any version of IE older than 9. Most are running IE 10, but a few, like myself, are running IE 11.

Comment: Could they possibly be running in compatibility mode? Otherwise I've got nothing.

Comment: No, not that either. That was the first thing I checked.

Comment: @JeffReddy Just for testing purposes what happens if you use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/. Also if there is any way you could post versions of firefox and maybe recreate in jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't have access to the source code. This is a site that we have maintained by another company.  So, I can't do the first.  I can look at it in jsfiddle though.